# If an inequality is true for $x \gt 0$, which is the interval $(0, x]$ then why can we use $[0,x]$ to prove the inequality?

Tags: inequality, proof-explanation

I have seen in a few online lectures the following pattern:

> We have an inequality, e.g: $e^x \gt 1 + x$ for $ x > 0 $, and we try to
>   prove this inequality with the mean value theorem using the interval
>   $[0,x]$.

Why is this possible if the possible interval for the inequality is $(0,x]$?

Comment: What says the mean value theorem and how do they use it to prove this inequality?

Comment: I imagine it goes like this: Let $x$ is an arbitrary positive real. Use the MVT on the interval [$0,x$] to argue that the inequality holds at the single point $x$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, you have shown that it holds for all positive $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay close attention to the formulation of the mean value theorem; when it's applied to a function satisfying the correct assumptions on the closed interval $[a,b]$, it gives you a point $\xi$ in the **open** interval $(a,b)$ such that $f'(\xi)=\cdots$.